# How do I have a Responsive Web Design image gallery?

Tags: css, html, mobile

Ok, so I am supposed to create an image gallery. The way I've envisioned it was for it to have a menu on the left, with the images appearing on the right, when selected from the menu. The menu would feature small thumbnails, and .... yeah, I wanted the site to feature a Responsive Web Design, where it would adjust itself should it be opened on a mobile device, but sadly I feel a tad overwhelmed by that.

What is my best way to approach this? I see some sites mention tips like
-make the mobile version first, and go from there
-be sure that the fonts change size depending on the screen size

And quite frankly, I don't even know how to make sure that my images are in the right size........ can anyone help? PLEASE!

Comment: only for new browsers or.... ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Newer browsers that support HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check media query on CSS3 : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can set the size of the pictures with this... You can make a simple css rules for desktop and make mobile css rules for mobiles by using

**CSS FILE:**

```
// CSS RULES FOR DESKTOP

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {// CSS RULES FOR MOBILE}
```

But I recommend you to include 2 css: one desktop and one mobile to be more clear.

Comment: It took a while, a lot of reworking, but it worked. Thank you! :)